# How to use RegEx extract in Eloqua?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, eloqua

im using Eloqua and theres a RegEx function, what I'm trying to achieve is to Extract all words after the first word and ONLY if the first word is [The]. An example here would be lets say i have a company called `The Abc Inc`, since the first word is [The], I want to extract only [Abc Inc]. How can I do this? I've tried a few ways `((?=[^The]).*)`, `[^The\s](\w+)`

Also Ive the system run this regex function only if the sentence contain the word [The], so anyhow i can just extract the second word onwards?

Here's an example to extract the domain from email address =  `((?<=@).*?(?=[.].*))`

Comment: Maybe you just need a capturing group? `^The (.+)`

Comment: Ok, then `(?<=^The ).+` will do

Comment: Hey @WiktorStribiżew ```^The (.+)``` works! didnt know it was that simple but thanks!